# How to test project's CMake minimum with GitHub actions?

Tags: cmake, github-actions

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.X.Y)` does not guarantee your CMake will work with CMake `3.X.Y`.

We currently have a python script that downloads the exact CMake minimum and tests our project against it. This helps catch problems every once in a while.

Is there a more elegant way to handle this problem with GitHub actions? Having a custom python script isn't ideal. Also downloading CMake like this is a bit slow since it's not cached by GitHub actions.

Comment: Please take a look at this action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-cmake. Apparently, it supports caching also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get-cmake` suggestion works beautifully!

Here is my implementation FWIW to future readers:

```
  test-cmake-minimum:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: lukka/get-cmake@latest
        with:
          cmakeVersion: 3.17.2
      - name: Create build directory
        run: mkdir build/
      - name: Run CMake
        working-directory: ./build
        run: cmake ../
      - name: Build
        run: cmake --build build/
```

Thanks to `get-cmake` for simplifying this!